# Can Z3 fpRealToFP be used for practical floating point accuracy proofs?

Tags: z3, z3py

I would like to use Z3 to prove the accuracy of certain floating point expressions. My plan was to:

1. Implement the expression as `Reals`.
2. Implement the same expression as `Float32()`.
3. Use `fpRealToFP` to create correspondences between the FP and Real consts.
4. Prove that the results are within some margin of error.

However, despite `fpRealToFP` existing, it seems to fail on even the most trivial tests.

```py
>>> import z3
>>> r = z3.Real("r")
>>> f = z3.Const("f", z3.Float32())
>>> z3.solve(f > z3.fpRealToFP(z3.RNE(), r, z3.Float32()))
failed to solve
>>> z3.solve(z3.fpToReal(f) > r)
failed to solve
```

Is there a reasonable way to approach this type of problem in Z3, or is this simply not something that it can do?

One approach that I've considered is to replace the `Real` part with a higher precision float, i.e. prove that the F32 result is within some MoE of the F128 result. This may be good enough to convince myself of probable correctness, but it wouldn't technically be a proper proof on its own.

Comment: A Z3 issue has been filed: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6548

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point from/to real conversions are extremely expensive. But I'm surprised z3 can't even handle the example you posted, as there are literally no constraints at all. Here's the SMTLib equivalent:

```
(set-logic ALL)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun r () Real)
(declare-fun f () (_ FloatingPoint 8 24))
(assert (fp.gt f ((_ to_fp 8 24) roundNearestTiesToEven r)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

z3 responds `unknown`, but `cvc5` does much better on it:

```
$ cvc5 a.smt2
sat
(
(define-fun r () Real (- 1.0))
(define-fun f () (_ FloatingPoint 8 24) (fp #b0 #b11111110 #b11111111111111111111111))
)
```

So, you might get better mileage by trying CVC5 on your examples. But keep in mind that once you have complicated constraints, all solvers will have hard time coping with these sorts of problems. Real/FP conversions create highly non-linear terms, and so far as I know no solver can deal with such problems all that well, at least not for the time being.

Comment: cvc5 working is interesting, thanks for pointing that out. The expressions I want to prove are mostly quite small, so maybe I'll get lucky in cvc5, although cvc5's python Windows situation may prove a hassle. I guess I'll mark this as answer if nothing better materialises, although technically it doesn't answer the question about doing this in Z3.

Comment: If Z3 can't handle this trivial `fpRealToFP`, does that mean that functionality is completely broken and that conversion function is useless? My naive assumption would be that if it can't handle this, it can't handle anything.

Comment: You might want to file an issue in the z3 issue tracker (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues). z3's FP theory has been rather neglected recently, so I wouldn't expect a quick fix but it might be nice to let the developers know about the problem. (Also mention CVC5 can handle it, so they have motivation to compete!)

Comment: I don't think the FP theory is broken: It's the conversions and mixing with Real's that causes the issue. If you stick to just floats, I trust it'll perform better. And I believe that'll be true for most solvers out there. (Of course, with any performance question, impossible to know without actually trying.)

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant only the Real -> FP and FP -> Real conversion being broken, not all of FP! Other FP stuff seems to work fine so far. But as far as I can tell, these conversion functions are currently completely useless - I haven't yet managed to get them to ever produce anything other than `unknown`.

Comment: I've filed an issue: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6548. I've been cheeky and quoted your answer.

Comment: Too bad the ticket is still open since it seems to generate an incorrect model. I wouldn't hold my breath on this being fixed quickly alas, but you never know.